# Wide to long data transform in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in the following format:

```
county   area    pop_2006    pop_2007    pop_2008
01001    275      1037         1052        1102
01003    394      2399         2424        2438
01005    312      1638         1647        1660
```

And I need it in a format like this:

```
county    year   pop      area
01001     2006   1037      275
01001     2007   1052      275
01001     2008   1102      275
01003     2006   2399      394
01003     2007   2424      394
...
```

I've tried every combination of pivot_table, stack, unstack, wide_to_long that I can think of, with no success yet.  (clearly I'm mostly illiterate in Python/pandas, so please be gentle...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) for reshaping, then [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) column `variable` and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) and [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). I think you can cast column `year` to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last change order of columns by `subset`:

```
df1 = (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['county','area'], value_name='pop'))
df1[['tmp','year']] = df1.variable.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.drop(['variable', 'tmp'],axis=1).sort_values(['county','year'])
df1['year'] = df1.year.astype(int)
df1 = df1[['county','year','pop','area']]
print (df1)
   county  year   pop  area
0    1001  2006  1037   275
3    1001  2007  1052   275
6    1001  2008  1102   275
1    1003  2006  2399   394
4    1003  2007  2424   394
7    1003  2008  2438   394
2    1005  2006  1638   312
5    1005  2007  1647   312
8    1005  2008  1660   312

print (df1.dtypes)
county    int64
year      int32
pop       int64
area      int64
dtype: object
```

Another solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df2 = df.set_index(['county','area']).stack().reset_index(name='pop')
df2[['tmp','year']] = df2.level_2.str.split('_', expand=True)
df2 = df2.drop(['level_2', 'tmp'],axis=1)
df2['year'] = df2.year.astype(int)
df2 = df2[['county','year','pop','area']]

print (df2)
   county  year   pop  area
0    1001  2006  1037   275
1    1001  2007  1052   275
2    1001  2008  1102   275
3    1003  2006  2399   394
4    1003  2007  2424   394
5    1003  2008  2438   394
6    1005  2006  1638   312
7    1005  2007  1647   312
8    1005  2008  1660   312

print (df2.dtypes)
county    int64
year      int32
pop       int64
area      int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

As the question title suggests, we can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
res = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames="pop", i=["county", "area"], j="year", sep="_")
```

to get

```
                   pop
county area year
1001   275  2006  1037
            2007  1052
            2008  1102
1003   394  2006  2399
            2007  2424
            2008  2438
1005   312  2006  1638
            2007  1647
            2008  1660
```

To exactly match the output format in the question, a `reset_index` and `reindex` (over columns) can be chained:

```
>>> res.reset_index().reindex(["county", "year", "pop", "area"], axis=1)

   county  year   pop  area
0    1001  2006  1037   275
1    1001  2007  1052   275
2    1001  2008  1102   275
3    1003  2006  2399   394
4    1003  2007  2424   394
5    1003  2008  2438   394
6    1005  2006  1638   312
7    1005  2007  1647   312
8    1005  2008  1660   312
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with
[pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/)

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = ['county', 'area'], 
    names_to = ('.value', 'year'), 
    names_sep = '_', 
    sort_by_appearance=True)
)
   county  area  year   pop
0    1001   275  2006  1037
1    1001   275  2007  1052
2    1001   275  2008  1102
3    1003   394  2006  2399
4    1003   394  2007  2424
5    1003   394  2008  2438
6    1005   312  2006  1638
7    1005   312  2007  1647
8    1005   312  2008  1660
```

For this particular reshape, any part of the columns associated with `.value` remain as column headers, while the rest are transposed into columns. you can also change the dtype of the transposed columns (this can be efficient, especially for large data sizes):

```py
(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = ['county', 'area'], 
    names_to = ('.value', 'year'), 
    names_sep = '_', 
    names_transform = {'year':int},
    sort_by_appearance=True)
)
   county  area  year   pop
0    1001   275  2006  1037
1    1001   275  2007  1052
2    1001   275  2008  1102
3    1003   394  2006  2399
4    1003   394  2007  2424
5    1003   394  2008  2438
6    1005   312  2006  1638
7    1005   312  2007  1647
8    1005   312  2008  1660
```

Answer (score 0):

Reshape df using pivot_longer.

```
import pandas as pd
import janitor

# Create the DataFrame
data = {
    "county": ["01001", "01003", "01005"],
    "area": [275, 394, 312],
    "pop_2006": [1037, 2399, 1638],
    "pop_2007": [1052, 2424, 1647],
    "pop_2008": [1102, 2438, 1660],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
"""print(df)
  county  area  pop_2006  pop_2007  pop_2008
0  01001   275      1037      1052      1102
1  01003   394      2399      2424      2438
2  01005   312      1638      1647      1660"""

# Reshape using pivot_longer
result = (
    df.pivot_longer(
        index=["county", "area"],
        names_to="year",
        names_pattern="pop_(.*)",
        values_to="pop",
        sort_by_appearance=True
    )
  
)
print(result)

"""print(result)
  county  area  year   pop
0  01001   275  2006  1037
1  01001   275  2007  1052
2  01001   275  2008  1102
3  01003   394  2006  2399
4  01003   394  2007  2424
5  01003   394  2008  2438
6  01005   312  2006  1638
7  01005   312  2007  1647
8  01005   312  2008  1660"""
```